# Proper JsonObjCodec with Fleece for Complex, Nested Discriminated Unions

Tags: json, f#, fleece

I have the following DU which is composed of other DUs or/and Records.

```
type BiometricRules =
        | Age of Comparator * AgeMeasure
        | Glycemia of Comparator * BiometricMeasure
        | Biometric of BiometricType * Comparator * BiometricMeasure
        | Sex of SexMeasure
        | MedicalCondition of MedicalCondition
        | Score of ScoreType * Comparator * ScoreMeasure
```

While trying to deserialize and serialize with [Fleece](https://github.com/fsprojects/Fleece), I have written the following `JsonObjCodec`.

```
with
        static member JsonObjCodec =
            Age <!> jreq "Age" (function Age (comp, ageMeasure) -> Some (comp |> string, ageMeasure |> string) | _ -> None)
            <|> (Glycemia <!> jreq "Glycemia" (function Glycemia (comp, bioMeasure) -> Some (comp |> string, bioMeasure) | _ -> None))
            <|> (Biometric <!> jreq "BiometricRule" (function Biometric (bt, comp, bm) -> Some (bt |> string, comp |> string, bm) | _ -> None))
            <|> (Sex <!> jreq "Sex" (function Sex s -> Some (s |> string) | _ -> None))
            <|> (BiometricRules.MedicalCondition <!> jreq "MedicalCondition" (function BiometricRules.MedicalCondition x -> Some (x) | _ -> None))
            <|> (Score <!> jreq "Score" (function Score (st, comp, scoreMeasure) -> Some (st |> string, comp |> string, scoreMeasure) | _ -> None))
```

For unknown reason it does not compile with error **No overloads match for method 'Map'.** All the nested DUs or Records have either a JsonObjCodec or static FromString and ToString methods defined.

Any solution with respect to how I could solve this via Fleece would be appreciated. The library is already deeply used in the project, so changing it would involve too much refactoring.

Below I copy pasted the definition of the other DU and Records, as reference:

---

```
    type Comparator =
        | GreaterThan
        | LowerThan
        | LowerThanOrEqual
        | GreaterThanOrEqual
        | EqualTo
    with
        override this.ToString() =
            match this with
            | GreaterThan -> ">"
            | LowerThan -> "<"
            | LowerThanOrEqual -> "<="
            | GreaterThanOrEqual -> ">="
            | EqualTo -> "="   
        static member FromString s =
            match s with
            | ">" -> GreaterThan
            | "<" -> LowerThan
            | ">=" -> GreaterThanOrEqual
            | "<=" -> LowerThanOrEqual
            | "=" -> EqualTo
            | _ -> failwith "Not a valid comparator."


    type AgeMeasure =
        | Years of decimal
        | Months of decimal
        | Weeks of decimal
    with
        override this.ToString() =
            match this with
            | Years y -> string y + " years"
            | Months m -> string m + " months"
            | Weeks w -> string w + " weeks"
        static member FromString (s: string) =
            match s with
            | _ when s.EndsWith("years") -> Years (Decimal.Parse(s.Replace("years", "")))
            | _ when s.EndsWith("months") -> Months (Decimal.Parse(s.Replace("months", "")))
            | _ when s.EndsWith("weeks") -> Weeks (Decimal.Parse(s.Replace("weeks", "")))


    type BiometricMeasure = {
        Value: decimal
        UoM: string option
    } with
        static member JsonObjCodec =
            fun va uom -> {
                Value = va
                UoM = if uom = "NA" then None else Some uom
            }
            <!> jreq "Value" (Some << fun bm -> bm.Value)
            <*> jreq "UoM" (Some << fun bm -> if bm.UoM |> Option.isNone then "NA" else bm.UoM |> Option.get)


    type BiometricType =
        | SBP
        | DBP
        | Glycemia
        | Specified of string
    with
        override this.ToString() =
            match this with
            | SBP -> "SBP"
            | DBP -> "DBP"
            | Glycemia -> "Glycemia"
            | Specified s -> s
        static member FromString s =
            match s with
            | "SBP" -> SBP
            | "DBP" -> DBP
            | "Glycemia" -> Glycemia
            | _ -> Specified s  


    type SexMeasure =
        | Female
        | Male
        | Other of string
    with
        override this.ToString() =
            match this with
            | Female -> "Female"
            | Male -> "Male"
            | Other s -> s
        static member FromString (s: string) =
            match s.ToLower() with
            | "Female" -> Female
            | "Male" -> Male
            | other -> Other other   


    type MedicalCondition =
        | ICD of ICD
        | Other of string
    with
        static member JsonObjCodec =
            ICD <!> jreq "MedicalCondition" (function ICD v -> Some v | _ -> None)            
            <|> (Other <!> jreq "MedicalCondition" (function Other v -> Some v | _ -> None))


    type ScoreType =
        | BMI
        | Other of string 
    with
        override this.ToString() =
            match this with
            | BMI -> "BMI"
            | Other s -> s
        static member FromString s =
            match s with
            | "BMI" -> BMI
            | _ -> Other s  


    type ScoreMeasure = decimal
```

Libraries Used:

```
    <PackageReference Update="FSharp.Core" Version="4.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="FSharpPlus" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Fleece.NewtonsoftJson" Version="0.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="FSharp.Data" Version="3.3.3" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Problem**

Fleece provides Json codecs, not string codecs, so defining `ToString` and `FromString` is not the way to go, unless you need them for other stuff.

**The solution**

Define `ToJson` and `OfJson` for your internal DUs. Then remove all the `|> string` fragments in `JsonObjCodec` body.

Here's a quick and dirty example (I advise error handling to be improved) for `Comparator` :

```
    static member ToJson x = JString (string x)
    static member OfJson x =
        match x with
        | JString x -> Ok (Comparator.FromString x)
        | _ -> Error (Uncategorized "JString expected")
```

**Alternative solution**

Leave all your internal DUs like this, but add the missing "parse" section in your `JsonObjCodec`:

```
    ...
    with
    static member JsonObjCodec =
        (fun (a, b) -> Age (Comparator.FromString a, AgeMeasure.FromString b)) <!> jreq "Age" (function Age (comp, ageMeasure) -> Some (comp |> string, ageMeasure |> string) | _ -> None)
    <|> ...
```

this becomes a bit verbose but will do the job.

**Tips**

- Instead of using the `<|>` operator to add codecs, you colud use the `jchoice` combinator, it will read better.
- If you really need your `String` / `FromString` methods I would suggest renaming `FromString` to `Parse` or renaming it to `TryParse` and returning an option type. This way you can take advantage of FSharpPlus `tryParse` function.
- Also, if you are using the string/parse pattern everywhere it might worth to create a codec combinator that works from transforming to/from strings. This is not an easy task but it might worth the mental effort.
- For debugging stuff like this purpose, try not to open the namespace `FSharpPlus` as it contains generic definitions of operators like `<|>`, `<!>` and `<*>`, this way you'll get better compile error messages.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and tips, @Gus. I've tried the alternative solution and it compiles. I tried defining for all internal DUs `JsonObjCodec` before and removed the `|> strings`, but it didn't work. 

1. Is there a reason for which it works only with `ToJson` and `OfJson` but not with `JsonObjCodec`?

2. Also, I have tried to find an example for defining `ToJson` and `OfJson` for DUs, but I was able to find on Github only for Records. Is there any link that I am missing? 

I plan to try the tryParse and to/from strings codec when I have spare time.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it doesn't make sense to define a `JsonObjCodec` for those internal DUs as they have a custom string representation, the method `JsonObjCodec` is aimed to compose existing codecs and create a dictionary that represents a JsonObject, but those DUs are JsonStrings, not JsonObjects. For those cases it's better to use the pair of functions `ToJson` /  `OfJson`. Fleece could also provide a single `Codec` overload but there would be little advantage as there's no guarantee both functions (serializer and deserializer) will get in sync, since they depend on your custom transformations.

Comment: Btw, when I implemented the alternative "parsing" in the `JsonObjCodec`, I assume the`JsonObjCodec` definitions for the `BiometricMeasure` and `MedicalCondition` kicked in, because I did not have to convert them using `FromString` in the parser:

`(fun (bt, comp, bm) -> Biometric (BiometricType.FromString bt, Comparator.FromString comp, bm)) <!>...
(fun mc -> MedicalCondition (mc)) <!> ...
`

Right?

Comment: Yes, for `BiometricMeasure` and `MedicalCondition` you can rely (and you should) on their existing `JsonObjCodec` definition.

Comment: btw: I just added an example of how to implement `ToJson` / `OfJson` to the answer.